# Convert tensor_forest model to tflite model by TFLiteConverter?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, random-forest, tensorflow-lite

How to use tf.lite.TFLiteConverter to get the tflite from tensor_forest model which could be using in the Android smartphone.

I found that the tensor_forest in the contrib directory ([link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest)). And there is an example using this model here ([link](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/2_BasicModels/random_forest.py)).

I add following code to save the model:

```py
saver = tf.train.Saver(save_relative_paths=True, max_to_keep=10)
checkpoint_prefix = 'checkpoints/model'

for i in range(1, num_steps + 1):
  (skip)
  if i % 50 == 0 or i == 1:
    saver.save(sess, checkpoint_prefix, global_step=i)
  (skip)
```

It generated the 'checkpoint', 'model-2000.data-00000-of-00001', 'model-2000.index', 'model-2000.meta' in the checkpoints directory. But I cannot convert it by referencing the using of tf.lite.TFLiteConverter cause it seems to need the pb file or missing some parameters.

How can I generate the tflite in the correct way?